# How to initialize Cloud Firestore Bean to use throughout all packages?

Tags: java, reactjs, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I tried following the firebase google documents for initializing the Admin SDK - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

This section of code is what I am referring to

```java
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

// Use a service account
InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccount.json");
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

But I ran into a few issues. Their documentation doesn't show how to use the initialized "Firestore db" variable throughout an application. They also use "FirestoreClient" which throws errors on compilation for me. I have a User class with a repository and DAO that I'd like to use to keep things structured. I'd like to Autowire a Firestore Bean to a DAO class so that I can use query my cloud firestore database.

Here is my main java class that starts the app:

```java
package com.nocturn;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.nocturn.user")
public class ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.class, args);
        try {
            // Use a service account
            InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("../../../resources/static/serviceAccount.json");
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my UserDAO class:

```java
package com.nocturn.user;

import com.nocturn.user.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;

@Repository
public class UserDAO {

  @Autowired
  private final Firestore db;

  public UserDAO(Firestore db) {
    this.db = db;
  }
    /**
   * Retrieves document in collection as a custom object.
   *
   * @return document data as User object
   */
  public User getDocumentAsEntity() {
    // [START fs_get_doc_as_entity]
    try {
      DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("41xfWB5B6josnRPYt55P");
      // asynchronously retrieve the document
      ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
      // block on response
      DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
      User user = null;
      if (document.exists()) {
        // convert document to POJO
        user = document.toObject(User.class);
        System.out.println(user);
      } else {
        System.out.println("No such document!");
      }
      // [END fs_get_doc_as_entity]
      return user;

    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

I obviously get errors about Autowiring the Firestore db because there is no bean created for it to autowire to. I tried creating a bean to return the Firestore variable inside my main class, but the FirestoreClient kept throwing errors. I'm unsure how I should have this set up.

I tried adding this to my main class, but still got some errors:

```java
    @Bean
    public static Firestore initFirebaseFirestore() {
        try {
            // Use a service account
            InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("../../../resources/static/serviceAccount.json");
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
            return db;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**When I don't create a bean:**
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.nocturn.user.UserDAO required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore' in your configuration.

**When I add the bean to my main class:**
 Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/tristanheilman/Documents/MapApp/src/main/java/com/nocturn/ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:[37,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable FirestoreClient
[ERROR]   location: class com.nocturn.ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication

Comment: If I take the @Autowired annotation off of the Firestore db variable in my UserDAO class the application compiles but when it goes to run the spring-boot app I get this error: InvocationTargetException: ...Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my answer. The main reason was incorrect imports:

```java
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
```

was needed and then also I was missing a few errors that gave indication that my serviceAccount.json file could not be created, hence the Firestore bean was null. I fixed that issue and the application started and I am able to use curl to tap into my cloud firestore database through the API's I created.